# How to get autocompletion of JSON responses of API calls within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, getjson, phpstorm

I was playing around with the gihub api and was wondering what kind of ways there could be to make static (in the containing properties returned sense) JSON responses known to the IDE so that I can work with autocompletion.

I tried to trick PhpStorm into thinking that the response has the following syntax, yet `currentUser = user.data;` makes resets the object and its properties are not shown in autocompletion

This is my approach:

```
var githubUser = {
    avatar_url: null,
    bio: null,
    blog: null,
    company: null,
    created_at: null,
    email: null,
    followers: null,
    following: null,
    gravatar_id: null,
    hireable: null,
    html_url: null,
    id: null,
    location: null,
    login: null,
    name: null,
    public_gists: null,
    public_repos: null,
    type: null,
    url: null
};



var github =  {
    githubApiUrl: "https://api.github.com",

    getUserData: function(userName) {
        $.getJSON(this.githubApiUrl + "/users/" + userName + "?callback=?", function(user) {
            var currentUser = Object.create(githubUser);
            currentUser = user.data;
            console.log(currentUser.login); // this is where I want to be able to use autocompletion
        });
    }
};

github.getUserData("k0pernikus");
```

Comment: Does PHPStorm recognize `Object.extend(currentUser, user.data)` instead of the assignment?

Comment: @Bergi Since my code was wrapped inside jQuery I used `$.extend(currentUser, user.data)` intead and got the autocompletion working. You can add an answer for me to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
currentUser = user.data;
```

overwrites the value. To get the `Object.create`-inheritance from `githubUser` working, you'd need to

```
$.extend(currentUser, user.data);
```